# Rotate lots of pages InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I have a booklet that is set out as a landscape orientation. This contains hundreds of pages. I need to be able to turn them all (with contents) to a portrait orientation.

Is this possible?

Comment: It may be quicker to export to PDF and rotate pages in Acrobat.

Comment: Check this link https://indesignsecrets.com/convert-portrait-to-landscape-with-layout-adjustment.php It's about how to prepare for easy page rotation. It can have something useful also for your case.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify whether you want to continue working on the rotated material in InDesign or whether this is just relevant as a finishing or exporting procedure? It looks like the answer strongly depends on this.